# Gerar número sequencial em java com Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Existe alguma forma de usando Hibernate gerar um numero personalizado para ser o numero de identificação de um determinado registro?

Tenho um sistema que armazena atendimentos realizados a um paciente, toda vez que um novo atendimento é criado é gerado pelo auto incremento do banco a numeração desse registro, porém gostaria que fosse gerado um numero mais composto tipo: (Ano - Mes - Dia - Hora - Minuto - Id do AutoIncremento)

Meu id está mapeado assim:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getRegistro() {
    return registro;
}
```

Gostaria de personalizar esse GeneratedValue, isso é possível? Procurei sobre isso mais fiquei um pouco confuso de como fazer, ainda sou iniciante com o Hibernate.

Comment: Fábio, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você poderia simplesmente ter um campo com o timestamp. Existe alguma razão para querer uma chave composta tão complicada? Isso somente tornaria seu programa e o uso dele mais complexo do que o necessário.

Comment: @utluiz muito obrigado pela atenção. Realmente analisando bem não existe motivo especifico para criar um código de identificação tão complicado e complexo. Até porque andei lendo e pesquisando e colocar o código de identificação com essa complicação pode me trazer problemas futuramente. Resolvi deixar como está mesmo, apenas fiz uma modificação para que o numero armazenado sempre fosse com 4 casas, ao invés de 1 ele ficará como 0001.

Comment: Legal, @Fabio. Se quiser, você pode postar sua solução como resposta à sua própria pergunta. Isso ajudará outras pessoas no futuro.

Comment: @utluiz muito obrigado pela atenção. Realmente analisando bem não existe motivo especifico para criar um código de identificação tão complicado e complexo. Até porque andei lendo e pesquisando e colocar o código de identificação com essa complicação pode me trazer problemas futuramente. Resolvi deixar como está mesmo, apenas fiz uma modificação para que o numero armazenado sempre fosse com 4 casas, ao invés de 1 ele ficará como 0001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sei que a pergunta é muito velha porem recentemente encontrei uma solução que resolveu agora essa minha dificuldade, vou deixar aqui pois, possa ser que alguem um dia precise.

Como deve ser declarado o campo que tera a numeração gerada

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "registro_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "registro_seq", strategy = "br.com.pegasus.util.RegistroPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = RegistroPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1") })
    private String registro;
```

Classe formatadora do Gerador (RegistroPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator)

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationHelper;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.type.LongType;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class RegistroPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "dateFormat";
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%tY";

    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%05d";

    public static final String DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_PARAMETER = "dateNumberSeparator";
    public static final String DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_DEFAULT = "0";

    private String format;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return String.format(format, LocalDate.now(), super.generate(session, object));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);

        String dateFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(DATE_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT)
                .replace("%", "%1$");
        String numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT)
                .replace("%", "%2$");
        ;
        String dateNumberSeparator = ConfigurationHelper.getString(DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_PARAMETER, params,
                DATE_NUMBER_SEPARATOR_DEFAULT);

        this.format = dateFormat + dateNumberSeparator + numberFormat;
    }

}
```

Necessario no banco de dados possuir essa tabela, que ira controlar a geração do proximo numero a ser gerado.

Tabela no banco

```
CREATE TABLE hibernate_sequence (
    next_val BIGINT(20)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO hibernate_sequence VALUE(1);
```

Pronto é isso, com essa modificação conseguir gerar um numero personalizado, para o ID

A solução não foi desenvolvida por mim, e sim depois de muito tempo procurando conseguir achar algo que resolveu minha duvida anterior de anos atraz, deixo o link da fonte, todos os créditos pela solução pertence ao autor.

Fonte: https://thoughts-on-java.org/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/

Answer (score 1):

Sim existe, basta você criar um gerador e especificá-lo na coluna que é o ID, no exemplo abaixo vou criar o id com base no modelo e ano do carro.

A entity:

```
@Entity
public class Carro {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "geradorId", strategy = "com.example.GeradorIDCarro")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "geradorId")
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String modelo;

    @Column
    private int ano;

    // getters and setters
}
```

E a classe que gera o ID customizado:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

public class GeradorIDCarro implements IdentifierGenerator {
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException
    {
        final Carro entity = (Carro) object;
        return entity.getModelo() + '-' + entity.getAno();
    }
}
```

[Referência](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158509/how-to-generate-custom-id-using-hibernate-while-it-must-be-primary-key-of-table).

Comment: Observação importante: A partir do Hibernate 5.2, o primeiro parâmetro do método `generate` passou a ser do tipo `SharedSessionContractImplementor`.